# Error - mismatched input 'SWAP' expecting 'REROUTE' in CrateDB for Alter Cluster query

Tags: cratedb

I am upgrading CRATE DB from version 2.x to 3.1.6 as per suggestion when I try to upgrade tables created in version 2.x using document,

https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/latest/admin/system-information.html#tables-need-to-be-upgraded

In step 5,

Query -

`alter CLUSTER SWAP table transactions2 to transactions;`

I am getting error `SQLActionException[SQLParseException: line 1:15: mismatched input 'SWAP' expecting 'REROUTE']`
I am not sure what would be the correct query to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

You are following the `latest` documentation instead of the e.g. `2.3` (https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/2.3/admin/system-information.html#tables-need-to-be-recreated) documentation version.

The `SWAP` SQL command support was added in version `3.2`, see https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/latest/appendices/release-notes/3.2.0.html#database-administration.